# PHP: How to pass in row name using bind_param

Tags: php

I need to make a row name be dynamic based on my choice. How can I make the following code work for me using bind_param?

UPDATE: main problem that my dynamic row name doesn't work. It gives me an error -

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object
```

Code

```
$myitem = 'something2';
$result = getResult($myitem);

function getResult($myitem) {
    global $DBconnection;
    $rowName = $myitem;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT
        id,
        something1,
        something2,
        something3
        FROM table
        WHERE ? = ? // ERROR
        ");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $rowName, $myitem); // ERROR
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $something1, $something2, $something3);
        while ($stmt->fetch()){                 
            $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'something1' => $something1, 'something2' => $something2, 'something3' => $something3);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        if (isset($row)) { 
            return ($row);
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Main problem not SQL injection, but that the script gives an error.

Comment: Prepared statements can only bind values, not identifiers.